# Dictionary<string, list<object>> return list by column name

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` of lists, each `List` is created from a `DataColumn`.

```
dict = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r[c]).ToList());
```

How do I now pass the values in a particular list to another variable based on column name (or column number would work)?

I'm basically trying to create an `XyDataSeries<double, double>()` for each list/column where the column values equal y & x=1++.

Something like this;

```
var xyData = new XyDataSeries<double, double>();
foreach (var i in dict."columnname")
{
   var one = 1;
   xyData.Append(one++, i);
}
```

**Update**

I have an error inside the foreach loop on the last line. The error states 'cannot convert from 'object' to 'double''.

```
XyDataSeries<double,double> xyseries;
var list = dict["ColumnName"];
foreach (var i in list)
{
    Convert.ToDouble(i);
    xyseries.Append(one++, i);
}
```

I tried to change `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<object>>> dict;`

to `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<double>>> dict;`

But this threw another error. I should note that the data is imported whilst the application is running and therefore the columns are empty at runtime however the above foreach is inside a checkbox checked event.

**Final Update**

Yeah I'm still learning... This works fine.

```
foreach (var i in list)
{
    var d = Convert.ToDouble(i);
    xyseries.Append(one++, d);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Keys` property:

```
foreach (var i in dict.Keys)
{
   // i is key in dictionaty -> ColumnName
   var listByColumnName = dict[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so does that mean i specify the ColumnName inside the loop rather than above? Sorry, I'm so new it hurts..!

Comment: @User9123, you iterate through all Keys in dictionary(in your case every key is column name). Using this key you can get data associated with this key in your dictionary (in your case data is list of some values)

Comment: @User9123: if you look at your code, you're storing the column names into the keys. So the answer, as @RomaDoskoch mentioned, is to use the `Keys` property.

Comment: So I have around 100 separate lists in my dictionary, if i wanted to return the values of one particular Column/Key, how would i do this?

Comment: @User9123, if your column name is i.e. `"AAA"` then  to get list for this column: `var list = dict["AAA"]`. Now you can iterate through values in this list.

Comment: @RomaDoskoch Thank you, i understand now. Is returning by index the done in the same manner? I.e if i wanted to return the fourth column `var list = dict[4]`

Comment: @User9123, to get fourth list your code should be: `var fourthList = dict[dict.Keys.ElementAt(4)];`

Comment: @RomaDoskoch Thanks, one last question. When using column name, is it case sensitive? Also is it ok if the column name contains a space or special characters such as ',# or, / for example?

Comment: @User9123, Yes, it is case sensitive and yes, it can contain spaces or other characters. The best way to check it is to try by yourself

Comment: @RomaDoskoch Thanks, I have been trying myself and i cannot seem to convert i from object to double when iterating through the list. I've put an edit in my question to show. Thanks

Comment: @User9123, which type of dictionary do you have - `Dictionary<string, List<double>>`?

Comment: @RomaDoskoch `Dictionary<string, List<object>>

Comment: @User9123, you should assign value converted to double and add it - replace this line: `Convert.ToDouble(i);` by this `var doubleValue = Convert.ToDouble(i);` and then `xyseries.Append(one++, doubleValue);`